# C code returns a 128-bit (GCC defined), I need to read this value

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm able to successfully call functions from my C library. The C code looks like this:

```
{
  void return128bit(*data);
}
```

I need to pass in a pointer to a 128-bit integer, but I am not sure how to do this. Other answers I have seen are from Python2 and either don't work or are not exactly what I need.

I have tried making a 128-bit struct in Python like so using c-types for a 64-bit array of 2 entries that I would then make a pointer out of:

```
class c_uint128(Structure):
    _fields = [
        ('value', c_uint64 * 2)
    ]

    def __init__(self, number = 0):
        super(c_uint128, self).__init__(number)
```

I have not tried passing this in because I can't even do basic things like initialize the 128-bit struct in python. This **init** function I found from another (6+ years old answer) no longer works and I get an error of `TypeError: too many initializers.`

Really all I need to do is call the C function and read the value it points to. It would be nice if I could also assign a 128-bit value to it as well.

Edit: I also am unable to cast the c_uint128 type to a pointer by doing

```
data = c_uint128()
datap = c_void_p(data)
```

```
TypeError: cannot be converted to pointer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class c_uint128(Structure):
    _fields = [
        ('value', c_uint64 * 2)
    ]

    def __init__(self, number = 0):
        super(c_uint128, self).__init__(number)
```

I realized `_fields` should be `_fields_`, which caused a lot of problems on its own. With this I was able to figure out how to use it as a 128-bit by adding some methods:

```
class c_uint128(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('int128', c_uint64 * 2)
    ]

    def __init__(self, number = 0):
        self.int128[0] = number & 0xffffffffffffffff           #lower 64 bits
        self.int128[1] = (number >> 64) & 0xffffffffffffffff   #upper 64 bits

    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.int128[1] << 64) | self.int128[0])

    def value(self):
        return (self.int128[1] << 64) | self.int128[0]
```

Overriding the arithmetic operators using self.value() to convert it to a regular python int makes it much easier to work with.

To pass it into a c function, I had to use byref():

```
def return128bit(data):
    lib.return128bit(byref(data)

data = c_uint128(41243)
return128bit(data)
```